# Error: spawn EACCES on gulp image resize with ImageMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, gulp-imagemin, node-imagemagick

I've found following error on while uploading images.

> "showStack":false,"stack":"Error: Error: spawn EACCES\n    at finish
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gulp-gm/index.js:40:21)\n
>   at gm.
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gulp-image-resize/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:485:30)\n
>   at emitMany (events.js:127:13)\n    at gm.emit (events.js:201:7)\n
>   at gm.
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:70:16)\n
>   at cb
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:322:16)\n
>   at gm._spawn
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:226:14)\n
>   at gm._exec
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:190:17)\n
>   at gm.proto.(anonymous function) [as size]
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:68:12)\n
>   at
>   /var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gulp-image-resize/index.js:46:16\n
>   at fn
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gulp-image-resize/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:582:34)\n
>   at Immediate.
>   (/var/www/projects/mywebsite/dist/node_modules/gulp-image-resize/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:498:34)\n
>   at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate
>   (timers.js:554:5)\n    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
>   (timers.js:533:5)","isOperational":true,"level":"error","timestamp":"2016-11-11T15:07:11.378Z"}

I've already changed folder permission to `755` but still encountered error. Please help me how to fix that issue.

I'm using `ng-file-upload` for file upload.

client code,

```
this.uploadLogo = function ($files, institute) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    var file = $files[0];
    if (file.size < 5000000) {
        $upload.upload({
            url: 'api/logo',
            method: 'POST',
            file: file,
            data: myformdata
        }).success(function (resp) {
            def.resolve(resp);
        }).error(function (err) {
            def.reject(err);
        });
    }

    return def.promise;
};
```

Comment: There are a whole host of reasons you can get an `EACCESS` error. You'll need to post some code showing what you're doing for us to help out. Also, 755 may or may not work. It'll only work if the owner of that directory is the same one running the script.

Comment: @samanime I've edited my question.

Comment: My guess is your GraphicsMagick `gm` executable itself is not both readable and executable. Figure out the full path to that file and do a `chmod a+rx full-path-to-gm`.

Comment: @PeterLyons `full path to that file` means gm file located inside node_modules?

Comment: No, the npm `gm` module is just a wrapper. You need your OS package for graphicsmagick installed to get the actual `gm` executable native program. `which gm` on the command line (assuming it's actually installed and your PATH environment variable is correct) should print the full path.

Comment: @PeterLyons I've found that response `/usr/bin/which: no gm in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/my-user/.local/bin:/home/my-user/bin)`. That seems `gm` is not installed?

Comment: Yes, that looks like graphicsmagick is not installed.